# Ruby on Rails - Select all child associations with a matching id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

- I have a `user`
- A `user` `has_many` `orders`.
- An `order` `has_many`
  `order_items`.
- `order_items` have a polymorphic association to `products` through `items`

I am trying to select all `orders` that have `order_items` that have a `product` that matches my `product_id`.

This is an existing codebase and a big refactor isn't possible at the moment.

I have approached the problem like this:

```
orders = current_user
          .orders
          .current
          .map { |order| order.order_items }
          .flatten
          .select { |order_item| order_item.item_id.to_s == product_id }
          .map { |order_item| order_item.order }
```

It works, I just want to know if there is a better or more "Ruby way" to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid querying for records in Ruby instead of Active Record

The main concern with the code as it’s currently written is that most of the querying is done using Ruby instead of letting the database handle it via Active Record.

As soon as you used the `map` method, you told Active Record to return the records from the database and instantiate them into memory.

By writing the entire query using Active Record alone, you’ll achieve much better performance, avoid multiple queries, AND the code will be simpler.

## Using `joins` + `where` clause

The key to your query is making use of `joins` to link up all the associations and `where` to filter them to the ones you want.

Start with this

```
current_user.orders.joins(:order_items)
```

From here you can use a `where` clause to filter by the `product_id` in question.

```
current_user.orders.joins(:order_items).where(order_items: { item_id: product_id })
```

The `where` clause is able to take a `Hash` as a parameter and you can use that hash to specify that you want to filter on a joined table (in this case the `order_items` table).

---

The documentation for this is here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

Answer (score 0):

Fetch record with single query instead of long ruby code

```
current_user.orders.left_outer_joins(order_items: :products).select("orders .* order_items.item_id = #{product_id}").group("orders.id")
```